# How to make the Save option on menu strip in Paint using C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a save option on my menu strip that should save whats drawn on the picture Box, currently I'm making in with SaveFileDialog but in the end I am saving a file **which I cannot open with any photo viewer**.

Here's the code:

```
    private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                using(StreamWriter swr=new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                swr.Write(pbCanvas.Image);
            }
        }
    }
```

https://pastebin.com/mU8TXPgW

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Comment: What does this code do, and what does it not do? It is not clear exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work:

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(@"FilePath",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```